# Bounded sequence of functions uniformly converges to bounded function

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

I'm working on the following question:

> True or False (and explain why or give counterexample). Suppose $(f_n)$ uniformly converge to $f$. If each $f_n$ is bounded then $f$ is bounded.

I think this is true, but I'm having trouble showing it. In particular, suppose the $M_n$ is a bound for each $f_n$ then:
$$|f_n-f| < \epsilon \\  -f_n - \epsilon < f < \epsilon + f_n  \\ -M_n - \epsilon < f < \epsilon + M_n$$

There's nothing controlling the growth of the $M_n$'s though. If $f_n$ are uniformly converging, I think the bounds should be close too, but I'm having trouble arguing this. Thoughts?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226604/if-f-n-converges-uniformly-and-each-f-n-is-bounded-show-that-exists-m) question is similar, but both answers skip the key detail that I'm hung up on.

Comment: The answer to your question is there. You just didn't understand the proof. After your first step the $n$ is fixed. The proof goes: Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then there is $N$ such that for $n>N$ you have that for all $x$, $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$. Fix $n>N$, say $n=N+1$. Then $-f_{N+1}-\epsilon<f<\epsilon+f_{N+1}$. Finally bound $f_{N+1}$ by $M_{N+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bound is correct for any given $n$ (depending only on the choice of $\varepsilon$). So just choose $\varepsilon =1$, find a suitable $n$ and fix that $\Rightarrow f$ is bounded.